# How do the horizontal scroller always visible in material table when the entire page is scrolled?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I always need a horizontal scroll bar in my website, when the page is scrolled.
I created the following sample with using material table.

[image: Edit rm0yx1knxq]

I found a sample [floatingScroll](https://amphiluke.github.io/floating-scroll/) what i want, but it is using the jquery. How can I simulate the behavior with material table in React? I hope always display the horizontal scroll bar in the red box.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There already is a horizontal scrollbar on the table.

Comment: @Nima I want to keep the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom even the Vertical scroll moves up or down.

Comment: I myself have never seen something like that. The horizontal bar belongs to the table component and not the whole page.

Comment: The floating-scroll website can demo what I want. Hence, I want to know how to simulate it in react.